# Obtain average of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, average

I am currently attempting to obtain an average result (on button press) of an array using the following code for testing purposes:

```
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {

    NSString *number1result = _number1.text;
    NSInteger number1int = [number1result integerValue];
    NSString *number2result = _number2.text;
    NSInteger number2int = [number2result integerValue];
    NSString *number3result = _number3.text;
    NSInteger number3int = [number3result integerValue];

    NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [resultsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:number1int]];
    [resultsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:number2int]];
    [resultsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:number3int]];

    NSNumber *avg = [resultsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.amount"];

    _arrayOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",avg];

}
```

However, when I run the application and press the 'calculate' button the debugging console returns:

```
2014-08-11 15:00:39.033 arrayTest[15259:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFNumber 0x109349c60> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key amount.'
```

Does anybody know what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **self** instead of **amount**:

```
NSNumber *avg = [resultsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];
```

If the array contained objects/dictionaries and you wanted to get average of a particular property/key then you could place its name instead like amount etc but here they are just `NSNumbers` so `self` is sufficient!

Comment: @user3258552 your welcome! Please accept the answer to close the thread!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
NSNumber *avg = [resultsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];
```

According to the error, the objects in the array don't respond to the `amount` selector. Makes sense, they're `NSNumber` objects. Your existing code would work if you had an array of objects (dictionaries, for example) that all respond to the key `amount`.

Comment: This solution was also viable, thank you. I also appreciate the explanative information!

Comment: Edited to correct the code -- as described in asifmujteba's answer, `self` is indeed the right term to use after the `@avg`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this for sorting the array. if you have not only number on your array. This kind like more manual

```
    float total;
    total = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;
    for(NSNumber *value in myArray){
        total+=[value floatValue];
        count ++;
    }

    float average = total/count;
```